# C# import excel to datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

i want to import excel file to datagridview1  and i am getting this error.
How can i solve this error?

Error   CS1061  'IExcelDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' and no extension method 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' accepting a first argument of type 'IExcelDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void dosyasec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx*", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
           // DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            result = reader.AsDataSet();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you download the newest version from a library but still using an old code example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into the same thing mentioned here: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/261

Basically, that reader configuration information is set differently now. Perhaps you either got your code from an outdated example, or this was existing code and the reader library was recently updated.  In any case, I think all you need to do is use the approach mentioned in the link:

```
var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
{
    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {
        UseHeaderRow = true
    }
});
```

Unless I've really goofed, that would make your existing method something like this:

```
  private void dosyasec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx*", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                var result = reader.AsDataSet(
                    new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true
                        }
                    }
                );
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```